# Fetch and echo data from second table based on value inside first table

Tags: php, sql, join, html-table, echo

I am trying to create a table/chart that has customers information in it.

I am setting a "work order status" status_id value for a customer when he/she checks in her computer with us as a numerical value.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/lNSBsMR.png]

In another table, I am storing statuses with the status_id and a status_text of the type of current statuses. So I can add more statuses based on type of work.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/KkLNPDG.png?1]

I was originally using Case switches like this and the case number would be corresponding to the value inside of the row.

```php
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM workorder";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {

//case switch
 $repair_status_color = "";
        $repair_status_text = "";
        switch ($row["status_id"]) {
            case 0:
                $color = "red";
                $repair_status_text = "Open";    
                break;
            case 1:
                $color = "blue";
                $repair_status_text = "Waiting";
                break;
            case 2:
                $color = "blue";
                $repair_status_text = "Waiting Parts";
                break;
        }

        echo "<td>" . $repair_status_text . "</td>";

}
```

I am trying to get the value from workorder table, check it against status table, and then echo the text from status_text from the table **Status** used on the status_id from the table **workorder**

I have tried this code

```php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM workorder INNER JOIN status ON workorder.status_id = status.status_id";
echo $row["status_text"]
```

But I am not sure I am doing it right. Anyone notice what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't got a column named `status_text` therefore, `$row['status_text']` will be unset (according to your screenshot) If you have, you must select it. You can use this to access it:

```
SELECT w.*, s.status_name AS 'status_text'
FROM workorder w
INNER JOIN status s
ON w.status_id = s.status_id
```

Or if you do have a status_text column you can do this:

```
SELECT w.*, s.status_text
FROM workorder w
INNER JOIN status s
ON w.status_id = s.status_id
```

You can now access it like so:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {
    echo $row['status_text'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have worked yours around and figured it out, where do i add commas to grab multiple associations, lets say I also want to grab pay_text from pay_id pay column.

Comment: `w.pay_text, w.pay_id, s.status_text` <-- w contains workorder columns, s contains status columns. :)

Comment: the pay is in a different table, how do I go about introducing another table PAY into this query? 

`SELECT w.*, s.status_text, p.pay_text
           FROM WORKORDER w 
           INNER JOIN STATUS s 
           ON w.status_id = s.status_id
           INNER JOIN PAY p 
           ON w.pay_id = s.pay_id` is that the correct way, doing multiple inner joins? @Jaquarh

Comment: Yeah, exactly like that :) You can have as many inner joins as you like as long as they're cross referenced correctly

Comment: hello @jaquarh, i have one more question if possible for you to help, let me know if possible i can link you to the stack exchange.

Comment: Sure, link it mate - Ill try my best